# Creating multiple instances of a component without multiple imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So currently I'm importing a component multiple times with different names.

```
import Page1 from "./Page/Page"
import Page2 from "./Page/Page"
import Page3 from "./Page/Page"
import Page4 from "./Page/Page"
```

I'm doing this as I want each instance to have its own set of properties, which then I use `<keep-alive>` to maintain their state.

I am also using them inside a `<component :is=""`.

I was wondering if there was a way to create multiple instances without multiple import.

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5x391j8y4x

you will notice that if I switch between the HelloWorlds, that the input will maintain their instances (input will change to what they were holding)

Comment: You shouldn't need to import the same module multiple times, you'll get the same instance back for each import (just with different names). Could you provide a bit more code that shows why you require to do it this way? I don't understand "each instance to have its own set of properties".

Comment: @DecadeMoon I've updated with a codesandbox to show what I mean (how I'm doing it at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) because you only have one component type that you want to use: `HelloWorld`. `<component>` is only needed when you want to dynamically render different component types.

The reason why you require [`<keep-alive>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) is because the `HelloWorld` component has local state (`msg`) which will be lost once the component instance is destroyed.

You will need to use [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) to force Vue to instantiate a new instance of `HelloWorld` based on the page, *and* you need `<keep-alive>` to prevent each instance from being destroyed when you switch between pages.

Here's an example:

```vue
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="page in pages"
    @click="currentPage = page" 
    :key="page.key">{{ page.title }}</li>
</ul>

<keep-alive>
  <hello-world
    :key="currentPage.key"
    :title="currentPage.title"/>
</keep-alive>
```

```es6
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'

export default {
  name: "App",
  
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },

  data() {
    const pages = [
        {
            key: "home",
            title: "Home"
        },
        {
            key: "about",
            title: "About"
        },
        {
            key: "contact",
            title: "Contact"
        }
    ]
    const currentPage = pages[0]

    return {
      currentPage,
      pages
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I knew there had to be a better way than creating multiples of the exact same component.